# How to make recursive function out of multiple for loops?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to convert the four successive loops below into a recursive routine.  I've been working on this to long; it's time to ask for help.

```
for m in range (len(main_liste[k])):
    if main_liste[k][m] not in verg_liste:
        verg_liste.append(main_liste[k][m])
        p=main_liste[k][m]

for m in range (len(main_liste[p])):
    if main_liste[p][m] not in verg_liste:
        verg_liste.append(main_liste[p][m])
        q=main_liste[p][m]

for m in range (len(main_liste[q])):
    if main_liste[q] not in verg_liste:
        verg_liste.append(main_liste[q][m])
        r=main_liste[q][m]

for m in range (len(main_liste[r])):
    if main_liste[r][m] not in verg_liste:
        verg_liste.append(main_liste[r][m])
        s=main_liste[r][m]
```

Comment: Fixed indentation; cleaned up problem description.

Comment: I'm not clear on what your code is trying to do.  I see that one result of each loop gives the row number for the next loop.  However, what makes you decided to stop?  What is the overall purpose of this code?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

If you want to make an 1D list (verg_liste) from a 2D list (main_liste) you can do something like this:

```
for m in range (that_many_m):
    for n in range(that_many_n):
        verg_liste.append(main_liste[m][n])
```

It would help to see a sample of main_liste and how verg_liste should look based on that sample of main_liste.